# display a list in PROLOG in specific format

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

How can i display a list :

```
Sorted = [p(201, 15, 2), p(301, 15, 3), p(401, 30, 4), p(501, 75, 5)].
```

in this format:

```
201 15 2
301 15 3
401 30 4
501 75 5
```

i used `display(Sorted)`, is there any other function to solve this ?

Comment: Also discussed at https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/sorting-predicates-in-prolog/5618

Answer (score 0):

```
forall(member(p(X, Y, Z), Sorted), format('~w ~w ~w~n', [X, Y, Z])).
```

Result in swi-prolog:

```
201 15 2
301 15 3
401 30 4
501 75 5
```